# Getting a Scoring Function by Name in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

In `scikit-learn` , there is the notion of a **scoring function**. If we have some predicted labels and the true labels, we can get to the score by calling `scoring(y_true, y_predict)`. An example of such scoring function is `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score`.

A scoring function is not to be confused of the `scorer`, which is an object that can be called as `scorer(estimator, X, y_true)`.

There are many builtin scorers in `scikit-learn`. It is possible to get to these scorers by their **string names**. For example, we can get the scorer corresponding to the name 'accuracy' by calling `sklearn.metrics.get_scorer("accuracy")`/

But it turns out that there is no obvious mechanism to access the built-in **scoring functions** by their names **at run-time, through passing in the name as a string**. For example, there is no way to access `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score` by its name `accuracy`.

For example, if at run time, the program knows the name of the scoring function is contained in variable `name`, I am looking for a mechanism `get_scoring_function()`, such that, `get_scoring_function(name)` will return the scoring function handle. Note that this name, `name`, is not known at scripting time.

Is there any way to access the built-in **scoring functions** by their names at run time through passing in the names as strings?

Comment: I mean that I want to get access to this function by its name -- i.e. "accuracy"

Comment: I clarified the question a bit, stressing that I am trying to get a function by its string name, and that I am after a function, not a scorer.

Comment: That is not my real issue. My real issue is to get to the built-in scoring functions by their names. For example, 'f1' should give me the f1 scoring function, `accuracy` should give me the accuracy scoring function, `f1-macro` should give me the f1-macro scoring function. I am looking for an accessor parallel to sklearn.metrics.get_scorer() but returns a function instead of a scorer.

Comment: I think I get where the confusion is now. It is because I did not say that I wanted to get the function by name at run-time. At run-time seems the key word to stress. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `get_scorer()` function, which accepts a string as an argument, and then get the `_score_func` attribute of the returned object.

So for example

```
from sklearn.metrics import get_scorer

get_scorer('accuracy')._score_func(y_true, y_pred)
```

is equivalent to

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 4):

I myself faced this task, and I haven't found a better way to access metrics by names than with `sklearn.metrics.get_scorer` function, but the drawback of it is that you have to pass an estimator there, not predictions. I tried to use the @collinb9 recommendation, but you see, you have to access a protected method there, and in my case, it led to unpleasant consequences, namely incorrectly calculated metrics.

This is a short example showing this problem.

```
from sklearn import datasets, model_selection, linear_model, metrics

features, labels = datasets.make_regression(1000, random_state=123)
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = model_selection.train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=567)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(train_features, train_labels)

print(f'variant 1 neg_mse = {metrics.get_scorer("neg_mean_squared_error")(model, test_features, test_labels)}')
print(f'variant 1 neg_rmse = {metrics.get_scorer("neg_root_mean_squared_error")(model, test_features, test_labels)}\n')

preds = model.predict(test_features)
print(f'variant 2 mse = {metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, preds)}')
print(f'variant 2 rmse = {metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, preds, squared=False)}\n')

print(f'protected neg_mse = {metrics.get_scorer("neg_mean_squared_error")._score_func(test_labels, preds)}')
print(f'protected neg_rmse = {metrics.get_scorer("neg_root_mean_squared_error")._score_func(test_labels, preds)}')
```

The output of this program will be:

```
variant 1 neg_mse = -2.142587870436064e-25
variant 1 neg_rmse = -4.628809642268803e-13

variant 2 mse = 2.142587870436064e-25
variant 2 rmse = 4.628809642268803e-13

protected neg_mse = 2.142587870436064e-25
protected neg_rmse = 2.142587870436064e-25
```

You see, metrics calculated with the use of the protected method differ. First, we ordered to get negative values, but got positive ones (it should be mentioned, that for `variant 2` metrics we didn't imply negative values). Second, the `neg_mse` and `neg_rmse` values are equal but should be different.

If we go to the source code of sklearn metrics, we will see:

1. [This is how `_score_func` is called](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb6117b228e2940cada2627dce86b49d0662220c/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L259): it is multiplied by sign, so that's where we lose our negative values.
2. [This is how scorers are made](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb6117b228e2940cada2627dce86b49d0662220c/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L696): you see, `neg_root_mean_squared_error_scorer` has extra parameter `squared=False`. This parameter is stated explicitly as an optional one in `metrics.mean_squared_error`, so you won't make a mistake. We can pass this parameter as a keyword argument to `_score_fun` and at least we will get a correct absolute value then:

```
print(f'protected neg_rmse = {metrics.get_scorer("neg_root_mean_squared_error")._score_func(test_labels, preds, squared=False)}')
```

```
protected neg_rmse = 4.628809642268803e-13
```

To make things short, I've shown, to my knowledge, the only way to get sklearn metrics by name (btw, you can find the full list of names [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)), and that it's not safe to use protected methods that you're not supposed to use. BTW, I was using sklearn version=0.24.2.

Answer (score 0):

Since the documentation is incomplete, you'll have to go directly to the source code here for the complete list of metric names:

[Metric Names](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/24593310d10e13efc364d17ce457dce0c7fa5df0/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)

Search for `__all__`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @collinb9 should not be accepted as it would lead to incorrect calculations.

You need other arguments (such as `squared:False` for rmse) to compute the correct thing. They can be accessed via the `_kwargs` attribute of `_BaseScorer` class. If you combine `_score_func` and `_kwargs` then we can get the corresponding scorer function.

The full answer to the question should be:

```
import functools
import sklearn

def score(scoring_name, y_true, y_pred):
    sklearn_scorer = sklearn.metrics.get_scorer(scoring_name)
    return sklearn_scorer._sign * sklearn_scorer._score_func(
        y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, **sklearn_scorer._kwargs
    )

score("neg_root_mean_squared_error", y_true, y_pred)
```